# How is adwords built?

Tags: algorithm, keyword, ads, google-ads-api

I want to know how an advertising network like adwords is built. What kind of systems display the ads and what kind of systems search keywords in the content of the publisher's website.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a spider which indexes the content of pages on its adsense network. The ads are pulled in with JavaScript. The actual algorithms which decide what ads to display on a page are closely guarded secrets. Google uses Python a lot, so odds are most of the backend uses that.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for a way to learn to build an ad network. Can you provide any books, tutorials, courses or systems that can learn me the basics of ad networks?

Answer (score 0):

To make this question approachable you need to specify what level/type of detail you want/need. Are you looking for a broad understanding of the information architecture and flow? do you need search/parse algorithms pseudo code/code? what exactly do you need?